# Divide by zero exception in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update statement which has division operation and one row throws exception

> Divide by zero exception

and I see that none of the rows got updated .

How to continue on exception so that rows which doesn't encounter 0 gets updated and row which has 0 fails? Its just a normal update statement without use of any transaction.

Comment: Exclude the rows in question by testing whether the values will result in an error in the where clause.

Comment: As Dale says, but if you want a more detailed answer, you should edit your question and include the query (or the outlines thereof).

Comment: The *real* question is what do you *want* to happen when you get a divide by zero error? If you simply don't want to affect those rows, then as @DaleK said, use a `WHERE`. What if you do want to still `UPDATE` them though? What value should a expression that was going to be divided by `0` resolve to? `NULL`? `99999999999999`? `0`? Something else entirely?

Comment: Include your SQL statement in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would filter out rows where the denominator is zero.  So, if your query is:

```
update t
    set ratio = numerator / denominator;
```

You would change it to:

```
update t
    set ratio = numerator / denominator
    where denominator <> 0;
```

Note that sometimes SQL Server evaluates the division for *all* rows despite the `WHERE` clause.  So, this is actually safer:

```
update t
    set ratio = numerator / nullif(denominator, 0)
    where denominator <> 0;
```